# Item with session: <sessionid>, reportPath: , userName: <username> not found in the database

Tags: ssl, ssrs-2008

In ReportManager I have many users complaining about this error. When I sift through the RS logs I see the following error many times for different users:

```
session!ReportServer_0-2!1e40!04/20/2011-09:13:56:: i INFO: LoadSnapshot: Item with session: zlq0epfrvvvfagbyyda2drbm, reportPath: , userName: PROD\user not found in the database
library!ReportServer_0-2!1e40!04/20/2011-09:13:56:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ExecutionNotFoundException: Execution 'zlq0epfrvvvfagbyyda2drbm' cannot be found, ;
 Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ExecutionNotFoundException: Execution 'zlq0epfrvvvfagbyyda2drbm' cannot be found
ui!ReportManager_0-1!216c!04/20/2011-09:13:56:: Unhandled exception: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: Execution 'zlq0epfrvvvfagbyyda2drbm' cannot be found (rsExecutionNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetExecutionInfo()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.SetExecutionId(String executionId, Boolean fullReportLoad)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.LoadFromUrlQuery(NameValueCollection requestParameters, Boolean fullReportLoad)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataOperation..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.GetHandler(String operationType)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Clicking on view report again, or hitting back on the browser and running the report again often seems to work - but I don't consider these viable solutions.

I've found dozens of postings on the web and have tried most of them without success. These included upping the SessionAccessTimeout & SessionTime values in the ReportServer.ConfigurationInfo database as well as setting reports to not timeout report execution and upping timeouts in the RS Web.config & rsreportserver.config.

This error will happen on reports that take seconds to run as well as longer running ones. We're running SSRS 2008 with RSWindowsBasic auth over SSL (this was recently changed from RSWindowsNTLM).

Any thoughts/input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following, this should fix the issue:

1. On the server, edit C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config
2. Set EnableAuthPersistence in rsreportserver.config to False

Regards,
M.R.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your issue is here :

```
PROD\user not found in the database
```

Comment: I've double checked that the user (in this case PROD\user) is in the RS db - not only that, but I can also find the session in the RS db ... still it complains that it can't find it.

Comment: Did you try to recreate from scratch the reporting services database ?